# global variables in xsl:template match patterns?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible in XSLT 2.0 to use node sets stored in global variables in xsl:template match patterns?

For instance:

```
<!-- GLOBAL PARAMETERS -->
<xsl:param name="tktDocRS" />

<xsl:variable name="tktDoc" select="saxon:parse($tktDocRS)" />

...

<xsl:template match="$tktDoc//someNodeInTktDoc">

...

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible in XSLT 2.0 to use node sets stored in global variables
>   in xsl:template match patterns.

**Yes, but a variable reference can only occur in the predicate**.

According to the eight syntax rules in the **[W3C XSLT 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#patterns)**,

a *pattern* is a union of *relativePathPattern*s (that can eventually be pre-pended by '/' or '//') and each *relativePathPattern* consists of *patternStep*s, each of which has the following syntax:

```
[4]   PatternStep   ::=   PatternAxis? NodeTest PredicateList
```

both the *PatternAxis* and the *NodeTest* cannot contain the `$` character, which means that variable references are allowed only in the predicates.

**Here is a very simple example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vOdds" select="/*/*[. mod 2 = 1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. = count($vOdds)]">
   <num special="yes"><xsl:value-of select="."/></num>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num special="yes">05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre! I like this approach.

Answer (score 4):

XSLT 3.0 (unpublished!) makes the following legal:

```
<xsl:template match="$x//a">
```

which will match any a element that has $x as an ancestor.

In XSLT 2.0 you have to write this as:

```
<xsl:template match="a[ancestor::node() intersect $x]">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [you can't put the variable reference as a step in a pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-syntax). And you don't have to, it should suffice to use

```
<xsl:template match="someNodeInTktDoc">...</xsl:template>
```

then you simply need to make sure you apply-templates on `$tktDoc`.

Comment: Thx. But what if the regular XML input for XSLT also contains elements named someNodeInTktDoc? Is there any way of forcing XSLT transform to choose only blocks stored in the variable?

Comment: @LukaszBaran: Yes: `match="node()[$var intersect .]"` Or, more imperatively: `<xsl:apply-templates select="$var"/>`

Comment: Lukasz, I would use modes (i.e. `<xsl:template match="someNodeInTktDoc" mode="m1">...</xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="$tktDoc" mode="m1"/>`) if I need to distinguish processing of nodes of the same name in different documents. Dimitre's suggestion is of course also an option.